# org-link-open fails with Wrong number of arguments: (1 . 1), 0

Tags: emacsclient, org-link, doom

I recently added a config entry to my `./doom.d/config.el` to enable Firefox as a default browser for opening links. Below is the entry I added based on this [post](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_set_default_browser.html).

```
;; Set specific browser to open links from emacs
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-firefox)
```

But after this, when I try to open a new link, I get `Wrong number of arguments (1 . 1) 0` error. Here is the debugger stack trace after enabling `toggle-debug-on-error`.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (1 . 1) 0)
  link-hint--open-org-link()
  link-hint--apply(link-hint--open-org-link "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yyYFggM3vx..." nil :open)
  link-hint--action(:open (:pos 205 :win #<window 3 on linkedin.org> :args "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yyYFggM3vx..." :type link-hint-org-link))
  link-hint--one(:open)
  link-hint-open-link()
  funcall-interactively(link-hint-open-link)
  call-interactively(link-hint-open-link nil nil)
  command-execute(link-hint-open-link)
```

Can anyone help figure this error out.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with `org-open-link`: the error comes from `link-hint--apply` which tries various things in sequence as long as they produce errors (see [the code here](https://github.com/noctuid/link-hint.el/blob/master/link-hint.el#L1221)):

```el
(defun link-hint--apply (func args &optional parser action)
  "Try to call FUNC with ARGS.
If PARSER is specified, first change ARGS by passing PARSER ARGS and ACTION.
First try `apply'. If there is an error (ARGS is the wrong number of arguments
for FUNC), `funcall' FUNC with ARGS. Finally, call FUNC alone."
  (when parser
    (setq args (funcall parser args action)))
  ;; TODO is there a way to know how many arguments a function takes?
  (condition-case nil
      (apply func args)
    (error (condition-case nil
               (funcall func args)
             (error (funcall func))))))
```

The problem is that something failed *before* the last failure which tried to call the function `link-hint--open-org-link` without arguments: since that function takes a single argument, calling it without any causes the error you see.

But the real question is why the previous two calls failed. So go to your `*scratch*` buffer which should be in `lisp-interaction-mode` and type:

```el
(apply #'link-hint--open-org-link "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yyYFggM3vx...")
```

except that you should give it the *FULL* URL (the error output elides part of it and replaces it with the ellipses `...` so I don't know what it should really be). Then press `C-j` after the closing paren and see what error you get. Is the URL correct? Can you open it in Firefox directly?

Then open an issue at https://github.com/noctuid/link-hint.el and tell them about the wrong error. No matter what, they should be reporting *all* the errors they get, not just the last one, similar to what Python does when it encounters an exception and during the handling of the exception, *another* exception occurs: just showing the last exception would lose important information. That's what happened here.